# How to fix this CA2000 for SqlCommand?

Tags: c#, .net, ca2000

I'm trying to execute a SQL query like following, but Visual Studio complains a CA2000.

```
public static IDictionary<string, string> TemplateDirectories(string connectionString) {
    var directories = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
        connection.Open();
        using (var command = new SqlCommand { Connection = connection, CommandText = "select * from PATHS" }) {
            var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
                directories[reader["CODE"].ToString()] = reader["PATH"].ToString();
                reader.Close();
        }
    }
    return directories;
}
```

> Error CA2000 ...object 'new SqlCommand()' is not disposed along all
>   exception paths. Call System.IDisposable.Dispose on object 'new
>   SqlCommand()' before all references to it are out of scope.

I tried several ways to fix it, but no one worked. So how to fix?

Comment: Try wrapping your reader in a using?

Comment: Hi @garethb I tried `using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {...}`, but this CA2000 still complained..

Comment: Answers are correct that it can be fixed by avoiding using the initializer - but why are you using one anyway? There's a specific constructor for `SqlCommand` that accepts the text of the command and an SqlConnection object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of a pitfall when using object initializers.

The way `SqlCommand` has been initialized, if there occurs some exception while initializing the object, the `SqlCommand` will be left un disposed.

So what is the solution. Declare the object in old fashioned way, to get rid of the warning-

```
using (var command = new SqlCommand())
{
    command.Connection = connection;
    command.CommandText="select * from PATHS";
    ...
}
```

I found a very good article around this, which gives more details and approaches to resolve the issue - 
http://haacked.com/archive/2013/01/11/hidden-pitfalls-with-object-initializers.aspx/

Having said that, for this perticular issue, it would be better to use constructor of `SqlCommand` and pass the command text and connection object like this (*courtesy: Damien_The_Unbeliever's comment*)

```
 string commandText = "select * from PATHS";
 using (var command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection))
 {
  ...
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try assigning the `command` parameters explicitly:

```
using (var command = new SqlCommand())
{
    command.Connection = connection;
    command.CommandText="select * from PATHS";
    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
        directories[reader["CODE"].ToString()] = reader["PATH"].ToString();
    reader.Close();
}
```